# React Native - How do I track and show overlay over another app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I need to track another applications in background (is it start or not, how long) and show popup over them in special time. How can I do it in react native? Will it work on ios and android?

Answer (score 2):

On iOS you cannot track if/when other applications are started and closed. Also you can't just simply put any overlays over any other app on iOS. You simply don't have access to any API that can do anything of what you want to do.